# Possible to have multiple websites, some with shared customers, some with separate customers?

Tags: customer, customer-session

I want to know if it is possible to have three websites, two of which would share the same shared set of customers, and the third would have an entirely different set of customers.

Can you let me know if this is possible, perhaps if there was a plugin that could allow this?

Or perhaps an alternative technique? Perhaps we set it up with separated customers on each website, and hourly, we sync customers between two of the websites?

Answer (score 1):

> Can you let me know if this is possible, perhaps if there was a plugin that could allow this?

No idea whether there is a plugin, out of the box it is not possible.

> Or perhaps an alternative technique? Perhaps we set it up with separated customers on each website, and hourly, we sync customers between two of the websites?

I would think about hacking the website id, while loading customers, so you could manipulate this.

Syncing customers every hour solves the problem too, but isn't that nice.

Whatever way you choose, both seem hacky.

Comment: I think your idea of hacking the website id whilst loading the customer is a decent approach. But yes, as you say, its not ideal for such a core function.